# linux: why if you pipe ps to grep, grep filter is in process output ? How does pipe works?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process

With a typical command like  `ps aux |grep foobar`  why `grep foobar` process is in output?

I was thinking that`ps aux` output was passed to grep to filter the lines by the pattern in grep argument but at the time you execute `ps aux` grep is still not executed (at least it's what I was supposing, I am wrong for sure), is executed later.

How does pipe works then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple:

1. OS starts the `grep` process (as the pipe target).
2. OS starts the `ps`, **which finds `grep` running**.
3. OS connects the standard output of `ps` to the standard input of `grep`.

Comment: Why it start the grep process before ps? because it will read ps output as the command is running so it's not executed sequentially ?